# SQL Server invalid object name insert

Tags: sql, sql-server

Recently I realized I should have a primary key in this table, so I tried to add one by doing the following steps:

- Added a new column with nullable values
- Filled all the values with integers indexed from 1 - 178
- Made the column not allow nulls - this saved fine with no warnings that there 
  were still null values
- I set the identity column to Id (new column I created)

Tried to insert a new row and got the following message

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 74, Procedure tr_dbo_SaveState_7d7e8c09-470a-4510-ac78-12bf952f3a14_Sender, Line 63 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Invalid object name 'dbo_SaveState_7d7e8c09-470a-4510-ac78-12bf952f3a14/StartMessage/Insert'.

I thought maybe I had to set the identity seed to the lastvalue+1 but still got the same message. I can insert into other tables just fine, and when I put the wrong number of arguments into the `VALUES()` function I get a different (expected) error, but when doing what I do for other tables, and used to do for this table I now get the above error. Does it seem the insert function is missing for this table? BTW this user has all permissions so that shouldn't be an issue

I also tried undoing this but it seems like the INSERT method for this table has just been deleted, or is somehow unavailable.

I can still select from the table just fine

When I try to update values I don't get the error message if the WHERE clause always results to false, but if there is a row that it tries to update I get an error message - this is not the case when I right-click on the table and Edit top 200 rows, only when I try and do it through query

Comment: off-topic, belongs on dba. But what does "i set the identity column" mean? And look the error message. Now look again. Does that name "tr_dbo..." look familiar? If not, go ask the person who wrote that trigger for help.

Comment: It's likely that this table has a trigger attached to it that's kicking off tr_dbo_SaveState stored proc.